# Couldn't start project on Android: It took too long to start the Android emulator: Pixel_2_API_30

Tags: react-native, android-studio

To run my react native application, I try to create & run an emulator in android studio and get this error every time.

*Couldn't start project on Android: It took too long to start the Android emulator: Pixel_2_API_30. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_2_API_30*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must wipe the data. For that go to **Device Manager -> Wipe Data**. After that restart your Android Studio. Then after your issue may be solved. Have a look on below mentioned image to get a better understanding.

[image: wipe data]

Answer (score 0):

Try clear your device cache data
Android studio -> virtual device manager -> on device actions select wipe data and then cold boot every-time

Comment: Thank you for your solution, But I solved it in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me,
If you run your project on VS Code, don't let automatically Emulator start after pressing a (run on android)
What I did is, I install VS Code Android Ios Emulator Extension and, I opened the emulator first through the VS Code.
After that, you can run "npm start" and press a to run the app on the emulator!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).